# urlpatterns = [...]+static(settings.STATIC_URL) get the escape symbol

Tags: python, django, settings

When I add STATIC_URL in the `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [...]+static(settings.STATIC_URL)
```

but there I get the `^static\/(?P<path>.*)$` in the urls.

Shouldn't it be `^static/(?P<path>.*)$`? like the `^media/(?P<path>.*)$`.

[image]

---

in `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

---

How to solve this issue? or is there another way to replace the

```
+static(settings.STATIC_URL)
```

if has, provide to me for testing, thanks.

Comment: Is the slash actually causing you a problem? The error message is for the empty path (e.g. `localhost:8000/`), so it doesn't have anything to do with static files. There are [other ways](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view) to serve the static files in development, but I'm not sure that's necessary in this case.

Comment: You can see the `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in my post.

Comment: As an aside, note that your `STATIC_ROOT` (where the static files are collected to) should not appear in `STATICFILES_DIRS` (where the static files are collected from).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to avoid that issue.
in the `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import serve

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT
        })
    ]
```

The result will like this:

```
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
^static/(?P<path>.*)$  # this is as the same with the media
```

Answer (score 1):

Static is used to direct the static url in local server mode. Unfortuntly
`static(settings.STATIC_URL)` seems to be a bit broken.

This seems to work in current django (2.2) :

```
from django.conf.urls.static import serve

urlpatterns += [
    path(settings.STATIC_URL[1:], serve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT })
]
```

After running `./manage.py collectstatic` the local server will serve all static files properly. Including django_debug .